# Running sh script via apple script raises command not found error

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I have an sh script that is not executable. At https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/applescript-bash-scripts-apps/ I learned that I could run the startBackend.sh script by double-clicking an apple script containing

do shell script "startBackend.sh"

without making the sh script executable. The apple script and the sh script are in the same folder. But when I run the apple script I get the

command not found error

error message. What am I doing wrong? My goal is to distribute the sh and apple scripts to my students so that they don't have to make the sh script executable by using the Terminal.

Comment: You need to add the path to the shell script; it doesn't automatically look in the same folder as the AppleScript. This is going to be trickier if the script is to be distributed, as the path will change. BTW, you will also need to make the shell script executable with `chmod +x /path/to/your/script.sh` (the `+x` parameter to `chmod` means "add eXecute permission").

Comment: So, I guess, the article I linked doesn't do what it says? The goal of the proposed strategy was being able to create for other people a "script that completely fixes their problem" without them "using the Terminal on their own". I cannot distribute a script that contain the path and they are supposed not to use the terminal.